# Why is the 2d matrix U not printing inside the main function?

Tags: arrays, c, function

```
int main() {
     double a, b, hx, hy, tol, max1;
     double h = 0.25;
     tol = 0.000000001;
     max1 = 100000000;
     a = 1;     b = 1;
     hx = h;
     hy = h;
     int n = (a / hy) + 1;
     int m = (b / hx) + 1;
     double **U = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double*));
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         U[i] = (double *) malloc(m * sizeof(double));
 
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
             U[i][j] = 1;
         }
     }
 
     LAPLACEWCG(a, b, h, hx, hy, tol, max1,U);
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("U[%d][%d]: %lf \n", i, j, U[i][j]);
         }
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("U[%d][%d]: %lf \n", i, j, U[i][j]);
         }
     }
     return 0; }
```

Why is the matrix not getting printed. If I try to print it in laplacewcg() it prints inside the while loop but it doesn't print outside it either. What needs to be changed in the code?

Comment: "...it prints inside the while loop.." Which `while` loop? Did you forget to post some code?

Comment: Anyway... if you don't get any prints in `main` it means that `LAPLACEWCG` is doing something strange... try to comment out that line... does it print after that?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311798/not-able-to-send-the-2d-array-to-a-function-from-main-but-it-works-if-i-declare]

Comment: @4386427 The link is to the full code. Can you please taka a look?

Comment: What happened when you commented out the line `LAPLACEWCG(a, b, h, hx, hy, tol, max1,U);`

Comment: @4386427 I did. It prints.

Comment: Add this line `printf("n=%d, m=%d U=%p\n", n, m, (void*)U);` **both** before and after the `LAPLACEWCG` line. What does it print?

Comment: @4386427 It prints before the function call. There's something wrong with the first function

Comment: Now just follow the same principle. Insert `printf` statements inside the function call so that you can see when it goes wrong. Alternatively use a debugger.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing to the LAPLACEWCG() function the U matrix value but you pass by reference. try:

```
LAPLACEWCG(..., &U);
```